# How can I display data of a table based on common attribute value between two tables?

Tags: python, html, django

[image]
I am trying to display all data from table 'Class'  based on common attribute value with table 'Student_class', where (Student_class.course_id==Class.id).There is an error.How can I solve this?

**models.py**

```py
class Class(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=111, default="")
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=111, default="")
    course_credit = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=111, default="")
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="", unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_title
    
class Student_class(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    answered_ques = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def my_class(request):
    current_user = request.user
    joined_class = Student_class.objects.filter(student=current_user).order_by('-id')
    all_class = Class.objects.filter()
    
    created_class = Class.objects.filter(teacher=current_user).order_by('-id')
    image = Profile.objects.get(user_id = current_user)
    params = {'created_class': created_class, 'teacher_name': current_user, 'image': image, 'all_class': all_class, 'joined_class': joined_class }    
    return render(request, 'course/my_class.html', params)
```

**my_class.html**

```py
{% for j in created_class%}
    {% for i in all_class%}
        {% if j.course_id==i.id %}
            <div class="service text-center">
                <a href="#"><img  src='{{image.profile_image}}' alt="Image" onerror="this.src='../../static/course/images/default-avatar.jpg'"
                  style="border-radius: 50%;width: 80px;height: 80px; margin-left: 130px;"class="img-fluid"></a>
                <div class="px-md-3">
                    <h3><a href="#">{{i.course_code }} {{i.course_title }}</a></h3>
                    <p>Course credit: {{i.course_credit}}<br> {{i.section}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**stack trace**

```py
TemplateSyntaxError at /my_class/
Could not parse the remainder: '==i.id' from 'j.course_id==i.id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_class/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '==i.id' from 'j.course_id==i.id'
Exception Location: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 663
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path: [
'D:\\django\\Course-Management-G35',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2018.9-py3.7.egg',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'
]
Server time:    Sat, 2 Jan 2021 16:11:27 +0000
```

Comment: can you add stack trace of error too

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: try changing `{% if j.course_id==i.id %}` to `{% ifequal j.course_id i.id %}`

Comment: Thank you. It works. But the code in ifequal statement is not executing(not displaying any value). Note: there will be joined_class instead of created_class in my_class.html

Comment: did you checked condition is working in backend.

Comment: yes, j.course_id returns string(which is the course_title of Class) and i.id returns int value(id no of Class).That's why condition is not satisfied. What can I do now?

Comment: can you confirm that in db there is proper data

Comment: solved, there was a problem in DB. Thank you.

Comment: please upvote comment/answer/question if it was helpful and can you upvote my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Change condition in template

From:

```py
{% if j.course_id==i.id %}
```

```
{% endif %}
```

To:

```py
{% ifequal j.course_id i.id %}
```

```
{% endifequal %}
```